# Apache virtual hosts not routing correctly

Tags: apache, xampp, subdomain, htdocs

I am creating my own intranet in my house. I am using my own fake TLDs from my hosts file. It is working great! That is until i try to create my second website using virtual hosts. So, i create my second website's index page, create a nice and comfortable folder right in my C:/xampp/ and add the following line for my second website in my virtual Hosts file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/sub1"
    ServerName homepage.masternet
</VirtualHost>
```

and create this line in my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       homepage.masternet
```

Please note that this entry is the only in my vhosts file since the other website is directly in my htdocs folder. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please explain what (unexpected) behaviour you're experiencing.

Comment: so then when i navigate to homepage.masternet, I don't get what index file is in my C:/xampp/sub1 folder, but I get what is in my regular htdocs folder.

Comment: Have you activated [name based virtual hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html)? Without that, it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Enable below line in httpd.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```